# Adding primary/foreign keys and referencing other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im having some troubles with key referencing. The Error comes from when i try to insert data into Table Mark

```
INSERT INTO Mark(examID, studentID, result, occured, noOFAttempts) 
    VALUES ('B10', '1', '67', '11-JUL-07', '1');
```

I get the error:

```
 integrity constraint  violated - parent key
not found
```

Context :

The tables Exam and Student represent data about college exams and
students. The exam results for the students, including the number of
attempts a student has had at an exam (noOfAttempts), are recorded in
table Mark by using the id column from Exam and the id column from
Student. Both id columns have unique values . A student has only the
latest result recorded for each exam.

Write a SQL command to create the Mark table. Include the primary keys
and foreign keys apparent in the tables specified above.

```
CREATE TABLE Exam (
 id VARCHAR(255),
 subject VARCHAR(255),
 noOfStudents INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
id INT,
name VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE Mark (
examID VARCHAR(255),
studentID INT,
result INT,
occured DATE,
noOFAttempts VARCHAR(255),
FOREIGN KEY (noOFAttempts) REFERENCES Exam(id), 
FOREIGN KEY (noOFAttempts) REFERENCES Student(id));
```

How do i fix the error i know its to do with wrong referencing, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the logic behind the `Mark` table makes sense to me.  It relates exams to the students who took those exams.  But the motivation to make `noOfAttempts` a foreign key does not seem to serve much purpose.  There *are* two foreign keys in that table, `examID` and `studentID`, and the combination of these two fields is also a primary key.  Here is what the `Mark` definition might look like to avoid these errors:

```
CREATE TABLE Mark (
    examID VARCHAR(255),
    studentID INT,
    result INT,
    occured DATE,
    noOFAttempts VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (examID) REFERENCES Exam(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES Student(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (examID, studentID)
)
```

Again, I don't see the point of making `noOfAttempts` a key of any kind, rather I think it should just be one regular column in the `Mark` table.

Edit per request from Gordon:

When you made your insert, you attempted to create a record in `Mark` which referred to parent records which did not exist.  In the case of your original table, you attempted to insert `'1'` as the `noOfAttempts`, but this ID did not exist in either the `Exam` and/or `Student` tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Update made, thanks for your vigilance here.

Comment: Thanks Tim and @GordonLinoff, this made my errors clear, updated the tables with data and it fixed the problem. Dont think im fully awake yet haha. thanks again